# How to add background color to the test in webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I found some text in webpage using below code

```
document.body.innerText.indexOf('tested')
document.body.innerText.includes('tested')
```

after finding the text I want to apply background color to that text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the reference of the element with your innerText:

```
let xpath = "//div[text()='tested']";
let element = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
```

Replace `div` with whatever type of element you have where the text is present

You can directly change the style once you have the element reference:

`element.style.backgroundColor = "red";`

Comment: can you please explain how to get the element from indexOf/ includes method. I found substring it is a part of a string.

Comment: i did not have the element reference

Comment: what is xpath here?

Comment: This might help https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp